# Define 2D array with C++ MATLAB API

Tags: c++, matlab

I'm using the MATLAB/C++ API.

I'm trying to create a 2D MATLAB array from a 2D C++ array. Here's what I've tried:

```
double testCppArr[243][5];

// Fill the testCppArr with data
mwArray *testMatlabArr = new mwArray(243, 5, mxDOUBLE_CLASS);
testMatlabArr->SetData(testCppArr[0], 243 * 5);
```

And that's created for me vector with length of 243×5, instead of a matrix with 243 rows and 5 columns. I know that's the same in memory, but I want to create a matrix and not a vector.

Where is the mistake?

I've also read [the MATLAB documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/setdata.html?searchHighlight=SetData), but didn't find a solution

Comment: I don't think you can do that in C++ (not an expert). As far as I know, to fill a 2D matrix, you need to fill it with a loop, iterating over the rows (243). Additionally. MATLAB data is 1D by nature (even if you created 2D matrices, they are 1D in memory), so even if you could copy a 2D matrix to a 2D matrix in C++, still you are not doing that, because the MATLAB one is 1D.

Comment: @AnderBiguri, thanks. you have an example of iterate copy?

Comment: Any example of memcopy of 2D arrays in C++ is a good starting point

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question define a 2D MATLAB matrix.
My problem was in the matrix data read.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis, the define 2d matrix code? if so, this is the code in the question